# Getting "Exception has occurred: AssertionError jinja2 must be installed to use Jinja2Templates" only when invoking "Debug Python File" in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jinja2, fastapi, uvicorn

First, I am new to Python and FastAPI.   I created a little project for myself to learn creating several APIs, including using templates.  I am working in a virtual environment using VS Code.   Running pip freeze confirms that Jinja2 version 3.1.2 is installed in the virtual environment.

```
(.venv) bash> pip freeze
..
..
Jinja2==3.1.2enter code here
..
```

I import Jinja2Templates in my main.py at line 15:

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
```

and reference this at line 54:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
```

This works fine when I start uvicorn from the command line in my virtual environment.  In an effort to step through and debug my code, I added the following to main.py:

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
      uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

When I attempt to debug by clicking on VS Code's "Debug Python File"

[Debug Python File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Ypr.png)

I run into the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: AssertionError
jinja2 must be installed to use Jinja2Templates
  File "/Users/smb/Documents/VSCode/Python/DBInstances/main.py", line 54, in <module>
    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and doing wrong?

As requested in first comment, I am pasting in the launch.json contents.

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
   // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
   // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
      {
         "name": "Python: FastAPI",
         "type": "python",
         "request": "launch",
         "module": "uvicorn",
         "args": [
            "main:app",
            "--reload",
            "--port",
            "8000"
         ],
         "jinja": true,
         "justMyCode": true
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your launch.json file into issue